# How do I secure my React Native Expo app from hackers?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, security, expo

I’d hate to build an entire application to only have it hacked.

I am using Firebase and Expo. I know about security rules for Firebase but is there any rules I need to abide by for the JavaScript within React Native/Expo?

Like, is there anyway a user can just change my javascript code and use it against me? I’ve heard about runtime attacks but I don’t know if people can do that in a mobile app like they can in a browser. I’ve seen where a user/attacker can literally just change variables and turn it into code that sends application data to the attackers server but I don’t know how that works.

Comment: You cannot trust code running on a device that is not in your physical control. Yes, they can change any variable or value or network request your app makes. As such, sensitive data should be protected server-side, not client-side. Firebase's security rules are one way here, if properly constructed.

Comment: Everything you send to the user, you should assume they'll break/exploit it. You need to write backend code that distrusts what's sent from the from the front end, and assume that you'll be compromised at some point when setting up your servers.

Comment: Never. Ever. Trust the client. Never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker could change js code on desktop and mobile. You can use [Obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) to make it more difficult. Something like [react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-obfuscating-transformer).

> I’ve seen where a user/attacker can literally just change variables and turn it into code that sends application data to the attackers server but I don’t know how that works.

Do you mean [XSS Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)? Such a case that a normal user send data to an attacker's server is mostly a xss attack. ([Here an example](http://www.insecurelabs.org/Search.aspx?query=%3Ch1%3ELoad%20here%20custom%20js%20to%20overwrite%20the%20normal%20site%3C%2Fh1%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27xss%27)%3C/script%3E)). But this would be an other topic